# Mysql not loading correctly

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.2

PHP 5.3.2
Apache 2.2.15
Mysql 5.1.X
Windows XP SP3

I have now configured everything correctly but get a timeout when trying to connect to Mysql via PHP. So frustrated.

I don't get an error message, the script just times out. I have made sure I have the correct paths.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Any idea why this might be happening? I do a php -v from the command line and everything is normal, no errors.

i upgraded PHP from 5.2.6 to 5.3.2 - does there seem to be problems or bugs with this? I am essentially using my previous PHP.ini while editing paths. I am lost. Help!

If you need anything from phpinfo() or httpd.conf or php.ini let me know. else

Comment: If you could just clear a few things up, that would be great. Is MySQL on the same box as Apache, or a separate database server? Are you using **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** or your DB server (if appropriate) in your mysql_connect() function? Have you tried adding **error_reporting(E_ALL)** at the top of the script temporarily to see if that helps?

Comment: Also worth checking, can you connect to MySQL via the command line with the same username/password as your PHP script?

Comment: mysql is on the same box. development machine. I'm using localhost and it's included in my hosts directory in Windows/system32/... hosts file. I have PHP set to E_ALL in the INI. PHP works, connecting to mysql times out. port is 3306 in the php.ini and its set as so by mysql.

Comment: I can login using mysql command line

Comment: Have you tried specifying **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost**? Since upgrading my laptop to PHP 5.2.13, localhost has never worked when connecting to MySQL via PHP, even though I have it set up in my hosts file. I realise you're on PHP 5.3, but I imagine if it broke in 5.2, it might well still be broken in 5.3?

Comment: it did work in php 5.2.6. Connecting to mysql now does not work in php 5.3.2.  it just times out.

Comment: In your php.ini file, what's your value of **mysql.connect_timeout**? If it's stupidly low, increase it a few seconds and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP 5.3.X + Apache 2.2.X on a Windows system it seems like one has to use 127.0.0.1 as localhost. This has not been the case with PHP 5.2.X in my trials. I will continue using php 5.2 until I can fully figure out what I am doing wrong.